# ASP.NET MVC 3 RC 2 Routing problem

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I changed the default routing in ASP.NET MVC from

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );
```

to

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default",
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}/{lineNo}",
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional, lineNo = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

but now all @Html.ActionLink() calls are rendered to href="". If I change the route back to default all links are working again.

I used the same route with RC1 and it worked perfectly.

I didn't find anything in the release docs so I think I'm doing it wrong.

Regards,
  Steffen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a route an optional parameter can appear only at the end. This means that in your route definition the `id` parameter **cannot** be optional. You need to explicitly set it to a value.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default",
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}/{lineNo}",
    new { 
        controller = "Home", 
        action = "Index", 
        lineNo = UrlParameter.Optional 
    }
);
```

And when you generate a link you must always provide a value for the id parameter if you want this route to match:

```
@Html.ActionLink("some link", "index", new { id = "123" })
```

As an alternative you might give a default value to the id parameter:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default",
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}/{lineNo}",
    new { 
        controller = "Home", 
        action = "Index", 
        id = "123",
        lineNo = UrlParameter.Optional 
    }
);
```

Now you no longer need to specify it in your links.

Comment: I don't know. Maybe it could have worked in previous versions but it is a route definition that doesn't make sense because if the id is optional the routing engine cannot disambiguate between the id and lineNo parameters. Maybe this rule has been enforced in RC2 which is a good thing IMHO.

Comment: Thanks. I splitted the rule in two parts and now it works fine.